# Don't update child component

Tags: reactjs

I have two children Components, when I onChange in first children, then the second children re render, I don't want to the second children re render. Online code example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ji-ben-antd-4-24-0-forked-efg56l?file=/demo.tsx

```
const ChildA = (props: {
  name: string;
  changeValue: (key: string, value: any) => void;
}) => {
  const { name, changeValue } = props;
  return (
    <Input
      value={name}
      onChange={(e) => {
        changeValue("name", e.target.value);
      }}
    />
  );
};

const ChildB = (props: {
  age: number;
  changeValue: (key: string, value: any) => void;
}) => {
  const { age, changeValue } = props;
  console.log("==when I change name====,  this component re-render");
  return (
    <InputNumber
      value={age}
      onChange={(e) => {
        changeValue("age", e);
      }}
    />
  );
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [saveValue, setSaveValue] = useState({
    name: "wang",
    age: 18
  });
  const showModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(true);
  };

  const handleOk = () => {
    // send value
    console.log("====saveValue==", saveValue);
    setIsModalOpen(false);
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
  };

  const changeValue = (key: string, value: any) => {
    const newValue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(saveValue));
    newValue[key] = value;
    setSaveValue(newValue);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={showModal}>
        Open Modal
      </Button>
      <Modal
        title="Basic Modal"
        open={isModalOpen}
        onOk={handleOk}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
      >
        <ChildA name={saveValue?.name} changeValue={changeValue} />
        <ChildB age={saveValue?.age} changeValue={changeValue} />
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
```

When I change the name ,I don`t want to Child B re-render

The actual situation is that there are many sub-components in a Modal. When you click OK, the value of the sub-component is obtained, saved and sent to the server. If you have good design component ideas, please share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want to the second children re render.

1. Wrap `ChildB` with `React.memo` for a basic memoization.

   ```
   const ChildB = memo(...);
   ```
2. Wrap the `changeValue` function with `React.useCallback` to persist the instance.

   ```
   const changeValue = useCallback(...);
   ```
3. Slightly modify the `changeValue` function so it **does not** use the `saveValue` as a *dependency*.

   ```
   setSaveValue((prev) => {
      const newValue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prev));
      newValue[key] = value;
      return newValue;
   });
   ```

[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ji-ben-antd-4-24-0-forked-f9xvdo?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: hello  I meet the new question,  ChildB props is Array, memo just shallow equality, it's also re-render.  What is the best way to deal with this situation? thank u ,and  thank u.demo is https://codesandbox.io/s/ji-ben-antd-4-24-0-forked-nsspui?file=/demo.tsx:0-2305